# Nodejs:Executing a shell command with switches & populating variables within that command

Tags: javascript, node.js

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to have the node_ip variable to populate the knife bootstrap command with the specific switches and bootstrap the node which is represented by that noe_ip variable. I am new to node.js ,any help is appreciated. How can I fix the issue and write this code better?

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;
child = exec("tugboat info test-node-004|grep -w Status|sed -r 's:\x1B\[[0-9;]*[mK]::g'|grep -o '[^:]*$'|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//'",
  function (error, stdout) {
    //process.stdout.write(stdout);
  if (stdout.indexOf("active")!= -1) {
          console.log('Node is ACTIVE');
          var child;
          child = exec("tugboat info test-node-004|grep -w IP|sed -r 's:\x1B\[[0-9;]*[mK]::g'|grep -o '[^:]*$'|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//'",
          function (error, stdout) {console.log("IP ADDRESS:" + stdout);
          var child;
          var user = "root";
          var path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa";
          var role = "'role[webmin]'";
          var node_ip = stdout;
          console.log(node_ip);
         var util  = require('util');
         var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
         var bootstrap = spawn('/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/knife bootstrap', ['-x', 'root'], ['-i', '~/.ssh/id_rsa'], ['-r', "'recipe[apt]'"], [node_ip]);
         bootstrap.stdout.on('data', function (data) {console.log('stdout: ' + data);});
         console.log(node_ip);
         })
        //console.log(stdout);                                                                                                                             
        }
//});
  else {console.log("Node is INACTIVE")}
});

I get this below error:
    root@app-test-001:~/chef-repo# node ~/test.js 
Node is ACTIVE
IP ADDRESS:103.xxx.yy.zz

103.xxx.yy.zz

103.xxx.yy.zz


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

`spawn` takes three arguments:

```
child_process.spawn(command, [args], [options])
```

`args` should be a single list of arguments to the command, so what you want is more like:

```
spawn('/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/knife bootstrap', ['-x', 'root', '-i', '~/.ssh/id_rsa', '-r', "'recipe[apt]'", node_ip]);
```